# Unable to connect to socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

I am unable to connect to socket.io when deployed on Openshift. It works well with c9 server.

Kindly tell if socket.io is supported by Openshift?

Comment: See here - https://www.openshift.com/blogs/paas-websockets

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code or an example of what you are doing?  You should try to connect on port 8000 for ws or 8443 for wss, and bind to port 8080 or your OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP on your gear.